# layering sound repeat? Swift

Tags: xcode, swift

I created an audio player. I can keep pressing my button and it will keep on replaying the sound. Hower when I press the button fast each time it replays the sound it cuts off the previous sound if the current sound is started while the previous one is still going. How can I keep on repeating the sound without stopping the previous sound? Kind of like layering the same sound?

```
func waterDropPressed(sender: UIButton!) {

    // Randomize a number for the sound
    var soundRandomNumber:Int = Int(arc4random_uniform(3))

    // Construct a string with the random number
    var soundFile:String = insultArray[soundRandomNumber]

    var insultURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource(soundFile, withExtension:"mp3")

    insultPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: insultURL, error: nil)
    insultPlayer!.prepareToPlay()
    insultPlayer!.play()

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've recently solved a similar problem in an app I'm working on. What I ended up doing was creating a different AVAudioPlayer for each "layer". If you know the number that will be playing at any one time, you might consider creating a pool of AVAudioPlayers for each "layer".  **The bottom line is that these AVAudioPlayers can't play two audio streams at the same time (even if it's the same audio stream).**  When I'm searching through my AVAudioPlayer pool for an available AVAudioPlayer I can determine which of these players is currently playing a sound by reading the player's `playing` property.  I, basically, grab the first one that isn't playing a sound and reuse it.  Another option is to dynamically generate a new AVAudioPlayer when you need to overlap sounds, but that introduces a slight bit of lag from the time you initialize the AVAudioPlayer and play the sound to the time the sound makes it out of the device.  Hope that was helpful. Good luck.